# How to upload image from gallery to android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on an app which include uploading pictures, I am able to select pictures using following. By this it is directly taking me to gallery, how can I display an alert(like whatsapp profile pic change) before it taking me to gallery.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_R);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pop up a dialog fragment when a user clicks your button or whatever to select a photo:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Set a Profile Photo");


        final String[] Items={"Select a Profile Photo"}; // You can add more choices here
        builder.setItems(Items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                if (i == 0){
                    // Your code to launch gallery here

                }
            }
        });
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        AlertDialog dialog=builder.create();
        dialog.show();
```

Check out more examples here: https://github.com/msandroid/AndroidUsefulExample_AlertDialog

Comment: When I've implemented that code it is taking me to gallery, but when I press on Back button while it is in the gallery window it is taking me to starting activity of the page instead of the activity where we clicked to upload an image